# trying to dinamically load data points to a google heat map layer

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I am trying to add to a google map a heat-map layer populated with data points from an SQL back-end. So far I managed to display the map and I do call a code behind method that return an arrays of JSON latitude and longitude points.

When I try to add the points to the heat-map nothing is displayed and I do not get any server or client side errors. below I pasted a snippet of the JSON I am passing to the java script function that should populate the heat-map layer, the html mark-up and the java script code.

The final result should be the heat-map layer displaying over the map. Currently only the map is displaying.

the "alert(data);" is displaying but the "alert(jsonData);" is not displaying

from c# I am using JSON.NET to serialize the data.

```
[{"CoordinatesObject":[{"Latitude":57.149605,"Longitude":-2.096916}]},{"CoordinatesObject":[{"Latitude":57.14871,"Longitude":-2.097806}]},{"CoordinatesObject":[{"Latitude":57.14905,"Longitude":-2.097004}]}]



 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 align-content-md-center">
        <div id="floating-panel" class="floating-panel">
            <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
            <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button>
            <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
            <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
        </div>
        <div id="map" class="map">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>

 var map, heatmap;

    function initMap() {
        var CenterLat = 55.95206;
        var CenterLong = -3.19648;

        var mapCoordinates = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(CenterLat, CenterLong),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapCoordinates);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: getPoints(),
            map: map
        });

    }//end InitMap

function getPoints() {

        var Json =<%=GetJsonData()%>;

        //var jsonData = JSON.parse(Json);

        for (var i = 0; i < Json.length; i++) {
            var LatLongObj = Json.CoordinatesObject[i];
            //ArrLatLong.push("location:" + new google.maps.LatLng(LatLongObj.Latitude, LatLongObj.Longitude));

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                'location': new google.maps.LatLng(LatLongObj.Latitude, LatLongObj.Longitude),
                'map': map,
                'weight': i
            });
        }
    }
```

please note that this is the first time I am playing with google map API.

**EDIT:**
**my working solution**

```
 var map, heatmap;

    function initMap() {
        var CenterLat = 56.816918399;
        var CenterLong = -4.1826492694;
        var ArrMarkers=[];
        var ServerData =<%=GetJsonData()%>;
         var Latitude ;
         var Longitude;

        for (var i = 0; i < ServerData.length; i++) {

            Latitude = ServerData[i].Latitude;
            Longitude = ServerData[i].Longitude;

            var marker = { location: new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude) };
            ArrMarkers.push(marker);

        }

        var mapCoordinates = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(CenterLat, CenterLong),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapCoordinates);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: ArrMarkers,
            radius: 15,
            opacity:0.5,
            map: map
        });

    }//end InitMap
```

Comment: To me it looks like data is already going to be an object.  So JSON.parse(data) won't work.  Note that getPoints isn't reading anything from the server, it's reading data that the server rendered when the page was loaded.

Comment: you are right and I have amended that function and now I am trying to figure it out how to loop through the Json var

Comment: It was only json on the server side.  Once it was written to the html it became a javascript array literal.  So arr.CoordinatesObject doesn’t make sense, it would have to begin with arr[index]...

Comment: I managed to get it working; see my edit on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FInal soultion**

```
var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
    var CenterLat = 56.816918399;
    var CenterLong = -4.1826492694;
    var ArrMarkers=[];
    var ServerData =<%=GetJsonData()%>;
     var Latitude ;
     var Longitude;

    for (var i = 0; i < ServerData.length; i++) {

        Latitude = ServerData[i].Latitude;
        Longitude = ServerData[i].Longitude;

        var marker = { location: new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude) };
        ArrMarkers.push(marker);

    }

    var mapCoordinates = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(CenterLat, CenterLong),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapCoordinates);

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: ArrMarkers,
        radius: 15,
        opacity:0.5,
        map: map
    });

}//end InitMap
```